# How do I replace values in a dict that are also keys recursively until no keys are left in the values?

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary

I have a `dict` like this:

```
d = {'a':'b+c', 'b':'f+g', 'f':'y+u'}
```

I want to recursively replace the letters in the values that are also keys, so I end up with:

```
d = {'a':'y+u+g+c', 'b':'y+u+g', 'f':'y+u'}
```

I tried using this code:

```
def getval(key,d):
    if d.has_key(key):
    temp=re.findall('\w+',d[key])
    for i in range(len(temp)):
        if d.has_key(temp[i]):
            getval(temp[i],d)
        else:
            continue

for k,v in d.iteritems():
    temp=re.findall('\w+',d[k])
    for i in range(len(temp)):
        if d.has_key(temp[i]):
            getval(temp[i],d)
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do it? My real dictionary is much larger, but definitely doesn't contain any cycles.

Comment: This can get dangerous: `{'a':'b+c','b':'c+a','c':'a+b'}`

Comment: @eumiro like this case wont come, i seen that entire dict

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams now i added the code which i tried and stucked

Comment: If this is homework, please add the "homework" tag. Also, `has_key` is deprecated, use `if temp[i] in d:`

Comment: @agf this is not homework i am working on some code like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with iterative methods like that is that their runtime is highly sensitive to the depth of the nesting and the order of the items in the `dict`. This recursive version runs in linear time with the total number of "segments" in the resulting `dict`, where a segment is each piece of the expression that came from one of the original values.

It also isn't dependent on what symbols are used, so long as the strings used as keys aren't used for anything else.

```
import re

# this function both returns and mutates
# so that each list only has to be flattened once
def flatten(lst):
    new_lst = []
    for i, item in enumerate(lst):
        if isinstance(item, list):
            new_lst.extend(flatten(item))
        else:
            new_lst.append(item)
    lst[:] = new_lst
    return lst

def flatten_symbols(d):
    # split the values using the keys as delimiters
    delims = re.compile('({})'.format('|'.join(d)))
    d = dict((key, delims.split(value)) for key, value in d.iteritems())
    # turn the value lists into recursive lists
    # replacing each occurence of a key with the corresponding value
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        for i, item in enumerate(value):
            if item in d:
                d[key][i] = d[item]
    # flatten the recursive lists
    return dict((key, ''.join(flatten(value))) for key, value in d.iteritems())


d={'s1':{'a':'b+c','b':'f+g', 'f': 'd+e', 'e': 'h+i'},'s2':{'a':'b+c','b':'f+g'}}

new_d = dict((key, flatten_symbols(subdict)) for key, subdict in d.iteritems())
print new_d
```

Comment: @-agf  if dict contains something instead of '+' if it contains '*1' or anything how we join that

Comment: @user1182090 I have updated code that should work. If you post your real data somewhere and link to it, so I can actually test it, I'll post it on your new question.

Comment: @user1182090 Meanwhile, you should vote up all the answers that tried to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I am actually not sure recursion is the most appropriate method here, here is a solution that makes replacements in a loop until none of the replacements change the current value:

```
import re

def make_replacements(d):
    r = d.copy()
    regex = dict((k, re.compile(r'\b' + re.escape(k) + r'\b')) for k in r)
    for k in r:
        done = False
        while not done:
            done = True
            for k2 in r:
                n = regex[k2].sub(r[k2], r[k])
                if n != r[k]:
                    r[k] = n
                    done = False
    return r

print make_replacements({'a': 'b+c', 'b': 'f+g', 'f': 'y+u'})
# {'a': 'y+u+g+c', 'b': 'y+u+g', 'f': 'y+u'}
```

Note that this doesn't detect any loops in the input, so if you give it something like `{'a':'b+c','b':'c+a','c':'a+b'}` it will enter an infinite loop (although it sounds like this should never happen from your comment).

Comment: thanks a lot for help, i need to learn re.... and can u say that change if dict of that type

Comment: if dict is of this type d={'s1':{'a': 'b+c', 'b': 'f+g', 'f': 'y+u'},'s2':{'a1': 'b1+c1', 'b1': 'f1+g1', 'f1': 'y1+u1'}}

Comment: @user1182090 In that case you could do something like `d = dict((k, make_replacements(v)) for k, v in d.items())`.

Comment: @-F.j that i got that, but when i running this code on entire dict of len around 900 lines, it showing       "n = regex[k2].sub(r[k2], r[k])
MemoryError"

Answer (score 0):

You need to put that code in a function. The line of your comment should then call that function on whatever you want to replace, put it into the string, and assign the result into the dict.

Comment: i am not getting can u help me

Comment: Is that code already in a function? If so, can you post the entire function (including declaration)?

Answer (score 0):

- This is an iterative procedure **with a fuse that blows with too many iterations** to check mutual infinite substitution.
- Uses regex to split the string with multiple delimiters
- Normalizes the string to
  remove whitespaces.
- Escapes the tokens, so you do not need to escape
  the delimiters

Try the following implementation.

```
>>> def replace(d,delims,limit=5):
    #Remove any whitespace characters
    d=dict((k,v.translate(None,string.whitespace)) for k,v in d.iteritems())
    #Escape the regex tokens
    delims=re.escape(delims)
    for i in range(limit): #Loop Limit, to prevent infinite Loop
        changed=False
        for k,v in d.iteritems():
            #Its best to use regex if multiple tokens is involved
            r="+".join(d.get(e,e) for e in re.split(delims,v))
            if r!=v:
                #Break if no change in any iteration
                changed=True
            d[k]=r
        if not changed:
            break
    return d

>>> replace(d,"+")
{'a': 'y+u+g+c', 'b': 'y+u+g', 'f': 'y+u'}
```

Comment: Don't use `has_key`, it's deprecated; use `e in d`. (I realize you probably already know that and just did what he did in the question.) Also, `d[e] if e in d else e` can be rewritten as `d.get(e, e)`.

Comment: [pep-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) - use lowercase for method names.